# "edit message as new" in outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I created a rule that delays sending messages, to avoid blunders.

Now when I send a message it is in 'Outbox' for a minute. But, what do I do when I have a blunder? I want to quickly find the message, open it in the editor, delete it from the outbox (so it will not be sent while I'm editing), edit and send.

The problem is that if I delete it from the outbox, Outlook will not send it. Copying the text and starting a new message is awkward (as I'll need to add all recipients again, or find the original message if this is a reply).

I guess the best thing would be to create a macro that:

- Found the messages in the outbox (assuming most of the time there will be one and if not, all the harm is sending more messages without touching)
- Open each as new
- Delete the messages from the outbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test your premise first in Outlook 2013. If I am editing an Outlook message that is in the Outbox with a Delayed Delivery, even if I go past the time, the message will not be sent. Are you, in fact, experiencing something different?

I use the Delayed Delivery feature for every outbound e-mail that I create as a message rule. It is set for five minutes. I have never run into your issue where an e-mail that I am editing is sent out. Once you click Send, the e-mail will go out immediately if you have not manually changed the Delay Delivery time and the time you originally set has passed.